# SC DPM detailed backup reporting

Tags: scdpm

We are currently using DPM 2019 to backup our servers on prem. Our weekly full backups go to tape and our daily incremental backups go to the disc pool. We are discussing doing online backups to Azure. We are trying to get a handle on the daily and weekly data volumes so we can size our storage vault (for pricing purposes) and evaluate our WAN connection. I have been unable to find any reports or tool that would help me do this. I've seen a couple or reporting tools, but they are either archived and not available or require that you are already do online backups and use Azure logs for the reporting.

Are there any free/inexpensive solutions that would help with this?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2):

You could start with an intermediate solution which is offloading periodic fulls to Azure, while keeping incremental up-to-date recent backups on-site for faster urgent restores. In this case you will a) know for sure how much you’ll push into Azure, easy to plan your capacity growth and bandwidth expectations, b) schedule offloads to cloud from foreground to background, not to stretch your backup window and not to overpay for immediate bandwidth not needed most of the time, and c) you’ll be able to restore from on premises data fast, no cloud restore is fast or painless. This is what we use with our DPM and Veeam tape-centric backup deployments.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/virtual-tape-library-on-azure-used-with-microsoft-system-center-data-protection-manager-2016

That’s with VTL running right in Azure which I don’t recommend unless your workload is there as well, but you should get the idea.